# Is there a way to create an annotation that extends the @ConditionalOn or is interpreted the same way in spring like the @Component annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have several implementations that use the same code base but we want them to do different things: i.e. rest access, administration via rest, indexing, archiving, and queue based.

In our infrastructure build out we want certain things to be accessible but other things not to be, such as in our administration/rest/indexing and archiving we don't want to buildout threads to monitor and handle queue requests, or in our indexing and archiving we want those processes, but we don't want the rest or queue build out.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to "extend" @ConditionalOnExpression with like an @ConditionalOnRest that extends @ConditionalOnExpression so we don't have to include the expression on each Component/RestController which we may have to change in a bunch of places or could be screwed up because it is functionally compile time checked and DRY.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have a custom @Conditional annotation so that you don't repeat the expression everywhere using `@ConditionalOnExpression`.

Comment: Yes, the answers below resolved the question.

Comment: Awesome! In that case please consider mark it as the answer so that the question can be solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways.

**Custom Annotation**

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ConditionalOnExpression() // add your expression
public @interface ConditionalOnRest {
}
```

**Custom Condition**

```java
class RestCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return // Your condition logic here
    }
}
```

Then you use it as follows:

```java
@Conditional(RestCondition.class)
```